# Capacitor connected to a battery

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

Capacitor connected to a battery:

What will happen if we connect a capacitor of higher potential to a battery of lower potential?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Comment: what do you mean by capacitor of higher potential?? Higher capacitance or higher dielectric breakdown value?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob, I suspect the OP is asking what happens if, e.g, a capacitor charged to 15V is connected to a 12V battery.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: Okayyy.....and we shouldn't answer, right?

Comment: I've put in my answer, but a bit of feedback for you might help.  A lot of these "what if" questions highlight something in your mental model of the physics that isn't quite right.  The good news is you realized it, and asked the question.  The bad news is, it can be hard for us to help unless you say something to explain why you think this isn't a trivial problem.  If you explain why, then we get more insight into your thought processes, and can help you better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for what will happen are the same as they always are: voltage will cause current to flow from the high voltage nodes to the low voltage ones.  It's pretty clear that, at first glance, the capacitor will discharge some of its voltage through the battery, driving the current in the opposite direction of what the battery usually would have caused.  This is always what happens when you hook up something with a high potential across something with a lower potential.  Battery, capacitor, generator, doesn't matter.

Where you may be lead astray is if you try to solve this sort of circuit in happy-go-lucky-ideal-circuit-land, which is right next to ideal-physics-land with its spherical cows and friction-less surfaces.  If you try to model the battery as an ideal voltage source, and the capacitor as an ideal capacitor, you'll find the equations just don't work.  They end up being contradictory because you can't have 12V on one side and 15V on the other.  The equations will refuse to work.  In ideal circuit land, this would be called "ill formed."  It's simply not a well formed circuit.

But you and I *know* that you can connect a battery to a capacitor, so how could it be "ill formed?"  The answer is that a battery is a whole lot more than just an ideal voltage source, and a capacitor is actually more complicated than the ideal capacitor with its neat and tidy equations.  There's parasitic resistances, parasitic inductance, and all sorts of effects that occur because batteries and capacitors are made out of real materials and they aren't perfect.  Of all of these effects, the most important to this particular circuit will be that a battery has an "internal resistance."  Rather than modeling a battery as an ideal voltage source, it's a bit more realistic to model it as an ideal voltage source in series with a resistor.  If you model it that way, you'll find that your circuit has an ideal voltage source (the low potential of the battery), a resistor (the internal resistance of the battery), and a capacitor (charged to the high potential of the capacitor), all in series.  *Now* you will find that the equations are more forgiving.  You'll see that the capacitor discharges through the resistor and the battery's voltage source.  The current in this loop will be equal to the voltage difference between the battery and the capacitor divided by the internal resistance of the battery.  From here, the equations just work like normal.  You'll see an exponential decrease in current as the capacitor discharges until it has the same voltage as the battery.

Of course, this is also only part of the story.  We modeled the battery as a voltage source and a resistor.  Real batteries have even more effects which can happen.  One of them is that some batteries behave *very* poorly if you overvolt them, meaning when you use a higher voltage (from the capacitor) to drive current backwards.  In effect, this charges the battery, and that can cause problems if the battery doesn't support doing that.

If you want to see what happens when you do bad things to a battery, consider [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAZ62tUtc0w) which highlights the dangers of treating Lithium Ion batteries poorly.  In this video, they rely on percussive maintenance to demonstrate the dangers, but overcharging them can cause similarly nasty behaviors!  Modern lithium ion batteries always come with some extra circuitry to monitor the condition of the batteries and make sure you can't overcharge them!